# What is include() in python? How is it different from import?

Tags: python, django

I am new to python and Django. I recently started with Django and in one of the tutorials I came across the following piece of code :

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

**What does that include statement do? How exactly is it different from an `import` statement?**

I know `import` statements are used to import some modules in python. And I read the following in the Django documentation already -

> A function that takes a full Python import path to another URLconf module that should be “included” in this place. Optionally, the application namespace and instance namespace where the entries will be included into can also be specified

I am not able to understand the above line. I did try reading the documentation and also made a lot of google searches, but nothing else came up.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.  A simple search will bring you to the package documentation.

Comment: What do you think `import` statement does? Isn't there an explanation of `include` in this tutorial?

Comment: `include()` isn't any sort of built-in Python statement; it's an ordinary function defined in one of Django's modules, and you will find an import statement for it at the top of the file.  The Django documentation is where you should look for details on what exactly it does.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I did try to read the documentation to my best potential, but could not understand it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just a quick and dirty answer.

Import is a very vital statement for python, whereas include is vital for django, but limited to django. Import is used to import python modules whereas include is used in django to give it Modularity for apps.

[Include()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urls/#django.conf.urls.include) :

> A function that takes a full Python import path to another URLconf
> module that should be “included” in this place. Optionally, the
> application namespace and instance namespace where the entries will be
> included into can also be specified

[Import](https://www.codementor.io/sheena/python-path-virtualenv-import-for-beginners-du107r3o1):

> To use any package in your code, you must first make it accessible.
> You have to import it. You can't use anything in Python before it is
> defined. Some things are built in, for example the basic types (like
> int, float, etc) can be used whenever you want. But most things you
> will want to do will need a little more than that.

**Update:**

URLconf is a file (usually called urls.py) that has all the url pattern mapping for given particular app. In your example Polls is a app that has a URLconf file saved as urls.py( that is placed in polls folder). Now to dispatch request to your app urls (say http://example.com/polls/stats) dango need to include your urlconf which it does by Include statement. You could write all the content of polls.urls inside the main urls.py and complete remove the `url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),`
Its not recommended because it looks ugly, increases repetition of code and removing app later on becomes a mess.

Comment: Why cannot we use import for URLconf ? As far as I know, that's also a module.